# Is it possible to use the output of a tag library to set the value of a HTML element in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, struts-1

Working with a struts 1 project, I'm trying to save myself hours of coding by using the output value of a JSTL tag to set the disabled property of some input boxes on a JSP page. unfortunately the following doesn't work:

```
<html:text property="name" size="15" maxlength="50" disabled="${not empty empRights}"/>
```

or

```
<html:text property="name" size="15" maxlength="50" disabled='<c:out value = "${not empty empRights}" />' />`
```

where empRights can only have **true** or **false** values. Is there anyway to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it. (None of which include arbitrary nesting of custom tags, which is never legal.)

If `empRights` can only be `true` or `false`, checking it for empty seems weird. The easiest would be to set a value based on it, but you need it to be `"disabled"` or `""` (empty), not `"true"`/`"false"`. Easiest is to use a ternary (assuming JSP 2.0+ container):

```
${empRights ? 'disabled' : ''}
```

(Or the opposite; not sure what you were trying to achieve via `empty`.)

Alternatively, set another variable and use that instead.

Comment: My knowledge of jsp is ok at best and I already questioned what the jsp coder was trying to achieve with empty also but since his knowledge supercedes mine I took his word for it.

Comment: Do you know the difference between the html and html-el tag libraries? Despite trying your suggestion it wasn't working and just as a last gasp attempt I changed the tags to html-el and it worked

Comment: @DarkStar1 Yes, the EL libraries allow the use of JSP EL expressions. This means you're either your container is mis-configured or it doesn't support EL.